# Java ArrayList removes non existing objects from parallel thread

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

Lately i was playing around with semaphores and multithreading, when i noticed, that something weird is going on with array list. More details:

I have some class with a single private ArrayList:

```
public class NewClass{

    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public void put(Object val){
        list.add(val);
    }

    public void del(Object val){
        list.remove(val);
    }
}
```

From some thread, i'm trying to remove elements from it (without putting anything before that):

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new SomeClass();
    }

    public SomeClass() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread tr2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NewClass nc = new NewClass();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        nc.del(i);
                }
            }
        };
        tr2.start();
    }
}
```

And when the thread starts working - i have no errors, no exceptions, etc. While, if debugging, i can clearly see, that list.indexOf(val); return -1 value - it actually does not exist, but is "removed". Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: can you please clarify this part **While, if debugging, i can clearly see, that list.indexOf(val); return -1 value - it actually does not exist, but is "removed". Can anyone explain what is going on here?**

Comment: What you are expecting from this program and what you are getting

Comment: There is not much multithreading going on here, as soon as `tr2` starts, the main thread is finished.

Comment: Do you add anything to your list at some point ?

Comment: and there is no parallel thread accessing your list!

Comment: ArrayList is not thread safe, use Vector insted in multithreaded environment and a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is needed.

Comment: It is just some part of "playing around with stuff" - just was checking what can, or cannot be done here. No result is actually expected.

Answer (score 2):

Lists don't throw exceptions if you try to remove things that aren't in it with the remove(Object o) method. They return false.

Comment: Ah, the index version returns the element.

Comment: Okay, i see now - looks like, when i was using something like remove(i), it was accepted not as Object value, but as index of an object - for that reason, it really returned null as result - no exception are thrown. Thanks for helping to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

- your `NewClass` instances are not shared across threads and each instance is accessed from only one thread.
- calling `List.remove(int index)` on an empty list does nothing special (it returns -1).

Answer (score 0):

Like as you said "playing around with stuff".

Am suspecting you have been caught between 
the two methods of ArrayList.

```
 public E remove(int index) // throws exception 

and 

 public boolean remove(Object o) // doesn't throws exception
```

When you are accessing through it thread you are actually passing it like an reference as an object. which actually calls the remove(Object o) method which doesn't throw exception.

While i think while playing around from single thread program you directly calling

list.remove(int) /// method which actually throws IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Thisis just my assumption as you haven't provided the code where it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

when you call remove, the list will become shorter than before. do you think your loop code is right? The total length is not 100 any more.